# An integral that can be solved by trigonometric substitution must be solved by algebraic substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

EDIT:THANK YOU FOR THE HELP, I am sorry I did not include my progress so far I will learn from all of your feedback

I am new to calculus 2 and I would appreciate some help, our teacher gave us this question:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{z^2-49}}{z}\,dz$$

He showed us the answer which is

$$-7\sec^{-1}\frac{z}{7}+\sqrt{z^2+49}+C$$

But the catch is we have to solve it using algebraic substitution, not trigonometric substitution. I am really stumped I can't seem to get that answer,  I would really be grateful for the help, I apologize if this question seems easy to you

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Your question may be downvoted or closed because it appears that you just want someone to work your homework for you. You should edit your question and add specifically what you have tried so far.

Comment: The answer is wrong. Just take the derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
u &= \sqrt{z^2-49} \implies z^2 = u^2 + 49\\
du &= \frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2} - 49}}\,dz \implies dz = \frac{u}{z}\,du
\end{align}
which gives us
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{z^2-49}}{z}\,dz &= \int \frac{u^2}{z^2}\,du\\
&= \int\frac{u^2}{u^2 + 49}\,du\\
&= \int \frac{u^2 + 49 - 49}{u^2 + 49}\,du\\
&= \int \left(1 + \frac{1}{u^2+49}\right)\,du\\
\end{align}

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Hi!  I'm really sorry may I ask how would integrating the 2nd term get me to arcsecant not arctangent? Thank you

Comment: It would give you arctangent.  As was mentioned in the the comments the given answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts and then apply $(\csc t)’= -\frac1{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}$ with $t=\frac x7$

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{z^2-49}}{z}\,dz=& \sqrt{z^2-49}-\int \frac {49}{z\sqrt{z^2-49}}\,dz\\
=& \sqrt{z^2-49}+7 \csc^{-1}\frac z7 +C 
\end{align}